# In dynamic query storing count(*) value into variable in sap hana procedure

Tags: hana

I have a requirement to store the count(*) value into a variable and then use this variable for business logic.I have written below code, but its not working. We have requirement to pass the schema name through input parameter hence using dynamic query inside procedure.

Code :

```
Begin

DECLARE v_count INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_Count_Query NVARCHAR(5000);

CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE RECORD_CNT_TABLE(RECORDS_CNT INTEGER);

v_Count_Query = 'INSERT INTO RECORD_CNT_TABLE(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "'||:IP_Schema_Name||'"."TABLE_NAME" where to_dats(to_char("LastRunDay", ''yyyymmdd'')) = '||current_date||';';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :v_Count_Query; 

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT RECORDS_CNT INTO '||v_count||' FROM RECORD_CNT_TABLE;';

IF :v_count >= 1 then
/**business logic**/
ELSE
/**business logic**/
END IF;  

END;
```

---

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The following works with HANA2 but not with HANA1.

```
create or replace procedure check_and_do_clients (IN schema_name Nvarchar(256))
as 
begin

DECLARE v_count INT := 0;   

    exec 'select count(*) from "' || :schema_name || '"."APPL_DATA"'
         ||' where "LastRunDay" = date''01.06.2017'' ' into v_count ;

    IF :v_count >= 1 then
              select 'WE HAVE A WINNER!', :v_count as vcnt, :schema_name as schema_name from dummy;
    ELSE
             select 'NO LUCK THIS TIME!', :v_count as vcnt, :schema_name as schema_name from dummy;
    END IF;  

end;
```

> 'WE HAVE A WINNER!'   VCNT    SCHEMA_NAME
>      WE HAVE A WINNER!    1       CLNT1

There really is no need for a temporary table here. And even if you plan to reuse the values outside the scope of the current transaction, then *creating* a *global* temporary table should not happen at runtime. 
Create it once and use `TRUNCATE TABLE` to empty it before you use it. The data will anyhow only survive as long as your session is active and only be visible to the session that created it.

More concerning than this is the broader design of the application for which you write this procedure.
Schemas in SQL are namespaces and as SQL is statically typed, a table `"CLNT1"."APPL_DATA"` is different from `"CLNT2"."APPL_DATA"`, which of course is the reason for why dynamic SQL has to be used in this setup.

Often, when I come across such designs, the schema concept is used for something more, specifically to have structurally identical copies of the same schema in different namespaces. The goal is to separate the data from different *tenants* or *clients* (in classic SAP speak) in the same database.

A common requirement then is to have the ability to do something from a "higher" position, accessing data in *any* of those client schemas. 
This is where your requirement seems to come into play.

There are a couple of issues with this approach:

- dynamic SQL is generally heavy on resource usage and prone to SQL injection
- it's - as seen - more difficult to write and only gets checked by the database at runtime
- the data access pattern breaks the model of a self-containing *client*-schema by opening direct data access by code not contained in the schema

An alternative approach for this could be to invert the design in this case.
Instead of having dynamic views onto X tables (one for each schema), create a  schema for tables common across the schemas and create filtered views in each schema instead.

That way the "master" schema could easily access the shared table without the need for any dynamic SQL just as the "client" schemas can access "their" version of the table in the shape of a view.
With the help of an `INSTEAD OF` triggers, it's easy to redirect `INSERT`/`UPDATE` statements against the views so that the filter condition is added appropriately.

This approach, just as the dynamic SQL approach, leave out the option for the actual client application that should run the procedure to dynamically switch to the schema of interest with the `SET SCHEMA <schema name>` command.
While `SET SCHEMA` doesn't help in the procedure (object references get checked statically at compile time, remember?) it is easy in a client application to issue the command and feed the result of the `SELECT COUNT(*)` back to the procedure that handles the further business logic.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lars. But currently in system we have SAP HANA 1 and above solution is not working into it. :(

Comment: I explained three solutions. If one doesn't work because you use an older HANA version, then maybe think about the other two!?